# Bash regex does not accept slash

Tags: regex, linux, bash

i am pretty new to bash shell scripting (and linux too)... i try to do a simple script which involves some regex for a string given by keyboard from a user.

```
            clear
            read -p "Insert e-mail > "
            if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[.] ]]
            then
                    echo "ERROR (code 1): e-mail cannot start with \".\""
            elif [[ $REPLY =~ .[.]$ ]]
            then
                    echo "ERROR (code 2): e-mail cannot end with \".\""
            else
                    if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z!#$%^\&\'*+-]+$ ]] #THIS IS WHERE I NEED HELP
                    then
                            echo "Good!"
                    else
                            echo "Bad!"
                    fi
            fi
```

so what i want to do is to make a regex
so that the user cant start with . or end with . (i pretty much did that and its working)...
next what i wanted to do was make the string start with a number and i did that with ^[0-9] (i think this is correct)
and after that..string could be anything like a number 0-9 or letters a-z and A-Z or the next characters: !#$%^&'*+-/
so when user entered 1& (it starts with number and the rest is in the acceptable characters) but it didn't work.. because it need to be \& (at the regex formula).
next the same problem occurred to character ' what i did, was to add again a backslash to regex formula (\') and it worked..
then i tried to do the same with / character (slash character) so what i did was add a backslash / (backslash slash) but when user entered 1/ (it starts with number and the rest are acceptable characters) unfortunately it printed "Bad!" ... it should print Good!..
why is that happening?
i tried \/ and \\/ but still... cant understand why it doesn't work!

Comment: I'm not sure why you need more than one line to ask your real (underlying) question. It could have a simplified regex that only matched the slashes themselves, too.

Comment: Also, the real problem has nothing to do with `/`s misbehaving in character classes, as you would have noticed if you'd built a simplified version of your regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is presence of `!` in your character class that is doing history expansion.

I suggest declaring your regex beforehand like this:

```
re="^[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z\!#$%^&/*'+-]+$"
```

Then use it as:

```
s='1/'
[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "good" || echo "bad"
good
```

Comment: Heh. I was editing appropriately, but you beat me there.

Comment: Yeah... that was the problem -.- Thank you.. but could you tell me what was the problem with !? i don't get what it does go wrong.

Comment: @Sotnam96: Having unescaped `!` causes history substitution to take place on command line. [See this Q&A for more details](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19252/why-does-the-exclamation-mark-sometimes-upset-bash)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `/`s work in character classes just fine:

```
$ [[ "1/" =~ ^[0-9][/]+$ ]]; echo $?
0
```